# Webpack vendor libs not splitted into separate bundle

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, webpack-plugin, dllplugin

I am trying to separate my vendor and app packages with the [autodll-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/asfktz/autodll-webpack-plugin) (`v0.4.2`). this package is a top level plugin over the [DllPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/) of webpack and the [add-asset-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/SimenB/add-asset-html-webpack-plugin) for auto-ordering the imports in the `index.html`.

What this plugin should do is separating the vendor libraries and the app code. I could do this with the [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) from webpack, but that way the bundle is regenerated on every recompile. Which is less efficient then generating the vendor bundle once and only recompile it when a lib has been changed.

---

**The problem**

I got this plugin to "work" (it is outputting a `vendor.bundle.js`). The only problem here is that when I inspect the `app.bundle.js` with [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) (`v2.13.1`). I can see that all the node_modules that are in the `vendor.bundle.js` are also loaded into this bundle, thus the plugin is not working correctly.

[image: app.bundle.js]

---

**Versions**

I am using:

- webpack `v4.11.0`
- babel-loader `v7.1.4`
- babel-core `v6.26.3`
- autodll-webpack-plugin `v0.4.2`

---

**Project structure**

My project has the following document structure:

```
App
-- build //Here are the output bundles located
-- node_modules
-- public
  -- index.html
-- src // App code
-- webpack
  -- webpack.common.js
  -- webpack.dev.js
  -- webpack.prod.js
-- package.json
```

---

**My webpack.common.js** (*This code is shared with the Dev & prod builds*)

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const AutoDllPlugin = require('autodll-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './src/index.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    publicPath: '', // Is referenced by the autodll-webpack-plugin
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['env', 'react'],
        },
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
    new AutoDllPlugin({
      inject: true, // will inject the DLL bundle to index.html
      debug: false,
      filename: '[name]_[hash].js',
      context: path.join(__dirname, '..'),
      path: '',
      entry: {
        vendor: [
          'react',
          'react-dom'
        ]
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autodll-webpack-plugin) of the `autodll-webpack-plugin` the context key should be used for separating. So I think this is where the problem lies.

The docs describe that you should reference the folder where the `webpack.config.js` is, but I have 3 of them, which one do I need to reference? And my folder is called `webpack` and not `config` that you see in the docs, is `..` also correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I didn't get the DLL setup to work. After reading some more I realized that the creator of the [autodll-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin) advises to use the [hard-source-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin) instead, because webpack is possibly going to use as a default option this in the future.

After reading some more I also realized that it is not advised to use the DLL plugin in production, since you have to recompile it anyways (dev build adds stuff). So you should use the `hard-source-webpack-plugin` for the dev build and the [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) for production.

I got these two to work quite easily:

**Webpack.dev.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    historyApiFallback: true, // Allow refreshing of the page
  },
  plugins: [
    // Enable hot reloading
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    // Enable caching
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin({
      cacheDirectory: '.cache/hard-source/[confighash]',
      configHash: function(webpackConfig) {
        return require('node-object-hash')({ sort: false }).hash(webpackConfig);
      },
      environmentHash: {
        root: process.cwd(),
        directories: [],
        files: ['package-lock.json'],
      },
      info: {
        mode: 'none',
        level: 'warn',
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    // Clean the build folders
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build'], {
      root: process.cwd(), // Otherwise the 'webpack' folder is used
    }),

    //Make vendor bundle size visible
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerMode: 'static',
      openAnalyzer: false,
      reportFilename: 'stats/prod-report.html',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        },
      },
    },
    minimizer: [
      // Optimize minimization
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          ecma: 6,
          mangle: true,
          toplevel: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
});
```

I hope this helps anyone.